# What is the cost of a harrow deck?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

In a campaign I'm starting up, I'm playing a wizard who wants to get into divination magic, and as I was reading around on D20PSFRG I saw mention of a harrow deck, which lead to much more reading.

However, one thing I couldn't find in my reading is how much it would cost to gain a harrow deck. The closest I can find is the details of the *Harrow Chosen (Human)* trait, in the fact that A) it's a trait that can give you a harrow deck (meaning it probably costs lest than 500gp, because that is how much *Rich Parents* gives you), and B) the replacement cost is equal to 300gp and a week's worth of time, which might also serve as a guide.

Other than that trait, I couldn't find anything about the cost of a harrow deck (not even in ultimate equipment). Is there a place I'm missing, or am I just going to have to figure a number based on the trait?

Comment: Costs $22 at the Paizo online store (sarcasm).

Comment: @Zangief Then I'll need to figure out the cost of teleporting it into the game world, because out here they don't do my character any good. ;P

Comment: I got you covered.

Comment: Honestly, i got that harrow deck and it's awesome. We make a reading at the start of every new campaign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harrow Deck is on page 57 of Ultimate Equipment and it has a price of 100 gp.

[image: page 57]

Comment: Seriously? I looked in ultimate equipment for like thirty minutes trying to find it. (Admittedly, not the whole time was looking for harrow decks... In my defense there are some really cool artifacts in there.)

Comment: It comes up with a description a few pages later aswell.

Comment: Guess we know what a nat 1 on perception looks like irl.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the harrow deck, a mat to lay your cards (a harrow mat) on and a case for the cards all on the archives of nethys site.

I can't access the site from this computer so I can't verify [this link](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Harrow%20deck). If it doesn't work a search on the site for harrow in equipment should show you all of the items.
The [Harrow Deck](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/gear/adventuringGear.html#harrow-deck) itself can be found on the PRD for 100 GP.